# Reading a file into a list on python. How to take out words

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am reading a file into a list and spliting it so that every word is in a list. However I do not want specific words to be brought up in the list, I would like to skip them. I called the trash list filterList written below.

this is my code:

```
with open('USConstitution.txt') as f:
    lines = f.read().split()              #read everything into the list

filterList = ["a","an","the","as","if","and","not"]  #define a filterList

for word in lines:
    if word.lower() not in filterList:
        word.append(aList)   #place them in a new list called aList that does not contain anything in filterList


print(aList)    #print that new list
```

I am getting this error:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'
```

Can someone help ? thanks

Comment: Got it the wrong way around, it should be `aList.append(word)`.

Comment: Is this the complete code? That code as its written right now should produce a NameError because `aList` isn't defined in scope.

Comment: Try "`aList.append(word)`" instead.

Comment: Unrelated to your issue, but `filterList` should be a set instead of a list  - for O(1) lookup instead of O(n).

Comment: Yeah, if you don't want duplicates in your list, it's a lot slicker to do:  
`words = set(f.read().lower().split())`
`good_words = words - set(filterList)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to give,

```
aList.append(word)
```

List object only has the attribute `append`.  And also you need to declare the list first. Then only you could append the items to that list.

ie,

```
with open('USConstitution.txt') as f:
    lines = f.read().split()              #read everything into the list

filterList = ["a","an","the","as","if","and","not"]  #define a filterList
aList = []
for word in lines:
    if word.lower() not in filterList:
        aList.append(word)   #place them in a new list called aList that does not contain anything in filterList


print(aList)
```

Comment: @Mozein - the introduction of aList in your posted code was incorrect, as mentioned by jwilner in the comments on your question.  Note that aList is defined to be a list in the updated answer.